# SQL update to pivot table and calculate new columnns

Tags: mysql, sql-update, self-join

I would like to pivot/reorganize a single column containing two variables into two columns with identical indices, and calculate the difference between these variables.

The below table definition shows that the two different dataTypes are identified by category, countryID, and year.

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Data (
  dataID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  category INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Categories (Category),
  dataType INT NOT NULL,
  countryID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Countries (countryID),
  year INT NOT NULL,
  values DEC(20,2) NULL);
```

The goal is to arrive at the following table:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Data (
  dataID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  category INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Categories (Category),
  countryID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Countries (countryID),
  year INT NOT NULL,
  dataType1values DEC(20,2) NULL),
  dataType2values DEC(20,2) NULL),
  type1-type2values DEC(20,2) NULL);
```

There are some 100+ countries, 25 years, and 5000+ categories. Despite quite a bit of research, I'm struggling with an efficient way to implement the (apparently) required self-joins. Please let me know if you have any questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes that every category/county/year has both type 1 and type 2 values. If you need to deal with rows that don't have both, it gets more complicated (especially since MySQL doesn't have `CROSS JOIN`).

```
create table NewData (<column definitions>)
select d1.category, d1.countryID, d1.year,
       d1.values as dataType1values, d2.values as dataType2values,
       d1.values-d2.values as values_diff,
       NULL dataID /* to allow auto-increment */
from Data d1
join Data d2 USING (category, countryID, year)
where d1.dataType = 1
and d2.dataType = 2
```

Comment: thanks, makes sense. there are indeed data for both types across all indices. How would I adapt your select statement to update the new (still empty) columns dataType2values & type1-type2values?

Comment: You can use a `select` statement as part of `insert`, to populate the table with the results of the query. I've updated my answer to show this.

Comment: Or with a `create table`, I've changed to that.